# Using OneDrive with Office365 ProPlus for Students

Tags: onedrive, office365

Is it possible to use OneDrive with an Office365 ProPlus for Students license?
If I try to login to OneDrive an error occurs which says the account doesn't exist but with the exact same credentials I can Login into the Office365 page.

Comment: No; It requires the business OneDrive client not the consume client

Comment: If I download the **OneDrive for Business** App I can use my students license?

Answer (score 0):

There are, unfortunately, "Two" OneDrives. There is the personal and the business versions. Your student subscription will come with the "business" one.

Sign into https://portal.office.com with your student account.  Then use the icon to launch OneDrive for business.  Once that is open just click the "Sync" link at the top of the page.  If you have the client already installed (you probably do if Office desktop is installed), it will fire it up and help you sync files.  If you don't have it, it will download and install for you.